# How can I fix “setenv command not found ” error ? (Ubuntu 12.04.4)

Tags: 12.04, command-line

I use Ubuntu 12.04.4. I install tcsh. But I still see this error :

```
No command 'setenv' found, did you mean:
Command 'netenv' from package 'netenv' (universe)
setenv: command not found
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have two options! Either run a `csh` compatible shell, or change the syntax of your command.

```
setenv VARIABLE value
```

is `csh` syntax (and you seem to know it). For `ksh` and `bash` the equivalent command is,

```
export VARIABLE=value
```

To run `tcsh` (after installing with `sudo apt-get install tcsh`) you can

```
tcsh
```

To switch your shell to `tcsh` "**permanently**",

```
chsh -s /usr/bin/tcsh
```

To switch back to `bash`,

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (but with u-boot), always using setenv and suddenly it puts an error.
I did use putty with other foreground color so I did a restart of putty with default color and setenv dit work again :)